# What's the shorest $k$-cnf formula in $n$ variables with exactly one satisfying assignment?

Tags: boolean-algebras

What's the shortest $k$-cnf formula in $n$ variables, measured by number of clauses, with exactly one satisfying assignment? The following construction achieves $n+2^k-k-1$ clauses.
Let $$C_{b_1\cdots b_k}=\bigvee_{j=1}^k\begin{cases}\,\,\,\,x_j&b_j=1\\\neg x_j&b_j=0\end{cases},\quad\quad\quad D=\bigwedge_{b\in\{0,1\}^k\backslash\{0\}^k}C_b.$$
and consider the formula
$$D\wedge \bigwedge_{j=k+1}^n(x_j\vee \neg x_1\vee\cdots\vee \neg x_{k-1}).$$
The $D$ clauses force $x_1=\cdots=x_k=\text T$, and the remaining clauses force $x_j=\text T$ for $j>k$.

Is there a bound which is sub-exponential in $k$?